# how to solve the error in cinder on openstack havana?

Tags: ubuntu, openstack

I am install openstack controller node for one machtion, and Another metchion running nova-compute only. so I am running controller node cinder will 
got error.

I clearly meantion it  which service gor error, so please help me.

cat /var/log/cinder/cinder-backup.log

1) ERROR cinder.service [-] Recovered model server connection!

2) 2014-11-28 12:43:35.415 4628 ERROR cinder.openstack.common.rpc.common AMQP server on 10.192.1.126:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 1 seconds.

3) ERROR cinder.brick.local_dev.lvm Unable to locate Volume Group cinder-volumes

4) ERROR cinder.backup.manager  Error encountered during initialization of driver: LVMISCSIDriver

5) ERROR cinder.backup.manager  Bad or unexpected response from the storage volume backend API: Volume Group cinder-volumes does not exist

scheduler:

1) ERROR cinder.service [-] Recovered model server connection!

2) ERROR cinder.volume.flows.create_volume Failed to schedule_create_volume: No valid host was found.

Answer (score 0):

Error:
3) ERROR cinder.brick.local_dev.lvm Unable to locate Volume Group cinder-volumes

4) ERROR cinder.backup.manager Error encountered during initialization of driver: LVMISCSIDriver

5) ERROR cinder.backup.manager Bad or unexpected response from the storage volume backend API: Volume Group cinder-volumes does not exist

Answer:
You check the file /etc/cinder/cinder.confg, and see vloume-group = (any name you created) same name you will create in $vg create (any name you created) that name only same it will worked.

Answer (score 0):

Error:

ERROR cinder.openstack.common.rpc.common AMQP server on 10.192.1.126:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 1 seconds.

solve:

You stop all the service in cinder, ofter First restart the rabbitmq-server, and you check rabbitmq start or not. give the commands $ ps -ef | grep rabbitmq, and
$ netstat -tulpn|grep 5672.

ofter start the services one by one and also check log files.